# Zf2 beginner - Using multiple database tables in one module

Tags: zend-framework2

I am a Zend Framework beginner, I have followed the Album tutorial but want to integrate more than one table into my module. I have tried a number of different methods but cannot get it to work.

I have two main entities, Contacts and Surveys, I have tried to create separate modules for each based on the Album tutorial but I am stuck when it comes to trying to call the functions within contact from the survey controller.

Should I be able to do this within the survey controller:

$contact = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Contact\Model\ContactTable');

The above code gives me an error like:

Undefined property: Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet::$firstname

Stuck, please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this in your controller:

return $contact->current();